# Sharepoint Custom Actions to remove Site action menu items

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, custom-action

I've been looking for hours on how to hide two buttons within the site actions menu (New Page & Manage Site Content and Structure).

Heres my specific case... I have a List which when a user is viewing, I want to be able to remove certain buttons. Also dependant if the user is an administrator, these buttons should show or not... Currently I have been able to remove these two buttons utilizing `HideCustomActions` (code below). The issue with hide custom actions is that there are no attributes to specify a list or content type for this to function off. Also there is no attribute like in `CustomActions` that will show the buttons to administrators only (Sample code of what I want to do in CustomActions below).

**HideCustomActions** code:

```
<HideCustomAction
    Id="HideCreatePublishingPage"
    GroupId="SiteActions"
    HideActionId="PublishingSiteActionsMenuCustomizer"
    Location="Microsoft.SharePoint.StandardMenu">
</HideCustomAction>
```

**CustomActions** code:

```
<CustomAction
    Id="HideNewPage"
    GroupId="SiteActions"
    Location="Microsoft.SharePoint.StandardMenu"
    RegistrationType="List"
    RegistrationId="10037"
    RequireSiteAdministrator="TRUE">
    <CommandUIExtension>
      <CommandUIDefinitions>
        <CommandUIDefinition Location="WHAT GOES HERE?" /> <!-- PublishingSiteActionsMenuCustomizer should go here but i dont have the id -->
      </CommandUIDefinitions>
    </CommandUIExtension>
</CustomAction>
```

If theres any details missing or if I am not explaining myself properly please let me know and I will update!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I understood you, you want to hide an action in the **Site Actions** menu just when you are in some special list / page.

This doesn't work out of the box. The [`HideCustomAction`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms414790.aspx) element simply doesn't offer to *"hide only when user is on page XYZ"*. Either it hides the action or it doesn't - that goes for all users everywhere. Especially when you're talking about the site actions menu which is (as the name implies) site wide.

Your only choice to do what you want, to hide the menu items only for certain users as well as only hide them on certain pages is to use JavaScript (or server side code). With the JavaScript you have to search for the menu items and hide them if your logic applies.